# How to create an index on foreign keys with kotlin exposed on a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm using Kotlin Exposed to define a table like so

```
object Headers : Table("headers") {
    val id = uuid("id").primaryKey()
    // tons more columns
}
```

And I have another table defined like this

```
object Transactions : Table("transactions") {
    val headerId = (uuid("header_id").references(Headers.id)).index("custom_header_index")
    // tons more columns
}
```

Now as you can see I'm attempting to create an index on this reference/FOREIGN KEY because if I try to query this relation I get the following result

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM  transactions WHERE header_id = 'bdbfc5d6-9cf1-430a-a361-a5f96cc7d799'

Gather  (cost=1000.00..13771.31 rows=8 width=171)"
  Workers Planned: 2"
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transactions  (cost=0.00..12770.51 rows=3 width=171)"
        Filter: (header_id = 'bdbfc5d6-9cf1-430a-a361-a5f96cc7d799'::uuid)"
```

It's doing a sequential scan. And since this table will contains hundreds of thousands of records this is unbearably slow.

I've tried a couple of things in order to get it to work but non of the syntactical changes seem to cause any schema changes

exampes:

```
// no infix
val headerId = (uuid("header_id").references(Headers.id)).index("custom_header_index")
// infix
val headerId = (uuid("header_id") references Headers.id).index("custom_header_index")
// index before reference
val headerId = (uuid("header_id").index("custom_header_index") references Headers.id)
```

I've tried all of these with and without custom index names.

I should also note that I'm using

```
SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(Headers, Transactions)
```

which on every other type of column detects an index change but not on foreign relations.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get kotlin-exposed to create these indexes?

**EDIT: CLARIFICATION**

Sorry my question didn't explicitly state that my problem is that Kotlin Exposed does not create these indexes. When I create them manually everything works as expected.

In the mean time I've also found the probable cause of this issue

```
for (table in tables) {
    val existingTableIndices = currentDialect.existingIndices(table)[table].orEmpty().filterFKeys() 
    val mappedIndices = table.indices.filterFKeys() // Here foreign keys are filtered

    existingTableIndices.forEach { index ->
        mappedIndices.firstOrNull { it.onlyNameDiffer(index) }?.let {
            exposedLogger.trace("Index on table '${table.tableName}' differs only in name: in db ${index.indexName} -> in mapping ${it.indexName}")
            nameDiffers.add(index)
            nameDiffers.add(it)
        }
    }

    notMappedIndices.getOrPut(table.nameInDatabaseCase(), {hashSetOf()}).addAll(existingTableIndices.subtract(mappedIndices))

    missingIndices.addAll(mappedIndices.subtract(existingTableIndices))
}
```

The code above is from the Exposed library and filters all indexes that it has to create and removes them if there is a foreign key on the column, making it impossible to create regular indexes on those columns.

I'll probably make an issue in their github repository and update this question if it's ever fixed.

Comment: I'm really sorry I totally forgot to mention that the problem is most likely with kotlin-exposed. I'm going to update the question in a moment to reflect that the indexes in fact are not created.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this in 2022, this works as expected in Exposed 0.39.2

Order of `index()` and `references()` doesn't matter, not if you use infix notation (this is just a syntactic sugar anyway)

One note is that checking if the index was created using `EXPLAIN PLAN` as shown here is not the best way, as the index may have been created, but your DB may have decide not to use it anyway.

A better way would be to use in PostgreSQL

```
\d transactions
```

That would describe your table and show something like

```
Indexes:
    "transactions_header_id" btree (header_id)
```

In this case.